# How to extract values after a 2nd time repeated symbol using regular expression

Tags: regex

For an example I have a value like this:

> "ConFst-DxtExBS1-NtrB1".

This is the regular expression I used to extract the value between '-' that is "DxtExBS1":

`-(.*?)-`

Now I want to write a regular expression that should extract the values after the 2nd repeated '-', that is "NtrB1".  I cannot say `1-(.*?)$` because the digit is not static. But the pattern will not change.

I think I only need to tell:

> begin after 2nd one hyphen
> then
> `(.*?)$`

Comment: I think that I only need to tell "begin after 2nd one hyphen" then '(.*?)$'

Comment: @CinCout Sorry for the difficulties I made for all of you guys. I think this is the 1st time I asking something here. Will follow as you said. Thank you for pointing out such a careless from me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

`"-[^-\s]*-([^-\s]*)"`

We essentially match every non-whitespace character which is not a `-` until the second `-` is encountered, then capture the rest until yet another `-` may or may not appear.

The captured group will have the text present after the second `-`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7cqfWB/1)

As per your comments, you can use this:

`-[^-]*-(.*)`

This matches until the second `-`, then captures the rest.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7cqfWB/2)

Comment: Hey, thank you for coming to help. I am getting an error "Syntax error: Illegal escape sequence: \s."

Comment: I think I just only want to tell "Begin after 2nd hyphen" then '(.*?)$'

Comment: You saved me @CinCout. It extracted the value I want. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following regex pattern:

```
=REGEXP_EXTRACT("ConFst-DxtExBS1-NtrB1", "[^-]+$")
```

### Demo

Comment: Hi. Thanks for replaying. First thing is; I actually want to extract the all value after the 2nd hyphen (-) that is "NtrB1". Though I tried with you said that will extract between hyphen. But I am getting an error "Syntax error: Illegal escape sequence: \K". 2nd thing is; the expression I used to extract between hyphen where successful. the expression was '-(.*?)-' and the result where "DxtExBS1". Now I want to extract the value after the 2nd hyphen. Again Thank you.

Comment: What is your regex tool or language?

Comment: Google Data Studio. I am trying to formulate a custom field using the supported function REGEXP_EXTRACT() function.

Comment: I have given you an option for finding the last component.